# how to embed RTL subtitles in a video (hebrew, arabic, ...) with the correct language directionality?

Tags: ffmpeg, video, subtitles, right-to-left

I try to hard-code subtitles in a video, by re-encoding the video with the subtitles as graphics (and NOT as an additional stream).

The subtitles are in Hebrew / Arabic.

(All texts are UTF-8 encoded. This is NOT a text-encoding / character-set problem.)

I'm open to other command-line tools, or programmatic solutions.

### The problem:

I want to be able to set sentence direction, for RTL subtitles.
`ffmpeg` doesn't seem to consider the directionality, so the result text is broken. It is being written visually, but not logically:

1. punctuations are written at the wrong side of the sentence,
2. sentense parts are broken: e.g. `<hebrew-text-A> <LATIN-TEXT-B> <heb-text-C>`
   is written:   `<heb-text-C>  <LATIN-TEXT-B> <hebrew-text-A>`

### The ffmpeg command:

`ffmpeg -i "nosubs.avi" -vf "subtitles='subs.srt'" withsubs.mp4`

### What I tried:

- I have tried the following subtitle formats:  srt, ass, ssa, vtt, ttml
- I tried to find RTL-related attributes or tags in the subtitles format; So far I have found none; TTML manuals do mention complex directionality-related, but I couldn't find examples, or where/how to implement them
- I have tried to set the language in the subtitles, where the format allows (ttml)

### partial success:

- I added manually a unicode control character, x200F, at the end of sentences/clauses.
  Which fixes the end-of-sentence issue(#1), but not the broken sentence(#2).

Another problem, is that I have to find a programmatic way to insert these control characters, which might take me days to do.

### Possible solution directions

- another unicode control character which controls whole sentences(???)
- a hidden ffmpeg switch to control langauge /  directionality, RTL setting
- specific subtitle-format setting, which is honored by ffmpeg.

### examples:

1. [this video](https://streamable.com/gahd6j) shows 1) broken sentence flow due to mixed hebrew/latin words, 2) some sentences begin with panctuation (which is wrong). 3) other sentences seem corect because i added control chars at the end of the sentence.
2. [sample subtitles file](https://ufile.io/o4l1186v) used to create the above video

### Irrelevant SO questions:

- set-a-subtitle-language-using-ffmpeg - refers to subtitles as stream
- how-to-fix-ffmpeg-mencoder-pushing-persian-rtl-subtitles-reversed - relevant but rejected from SO, no answers given
- how-to-properly-convert-rtl-subtitles-in-ffmpeg - talks about charset, not directionality
- 